# how to change the ftp passive mode ip address for haproxy work as reserve proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, linux-networking, haproxy, ip-address

I have an ftp server in LAN, address is 192.168.1.11
I used haproxy is because lots of other service need it

I put haproxy on my 192.168.1.1 the same machine of our soft-route(ubuntu 14.04)

My haproxy config is:

```
frontend ao3-ftp
bind ftp.ao3.com.au:21
bind ftp.ao3.com.au:20
bind ftp.ao3.com.au:5000-5100
default_backend myftp

 backend myftp 
server server1 192.168.1.11
```

when the client use the ftp service they find the problem of the iternal ip address can not connected：

```
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
Reply: 220 Hi welcome to Ao3 ftp Server
Reply: 200 Don't care
Command: USER ingram
Reply: 331 Password required for ingram
Command: PASS ***********
Reply: 230 Logged on
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Features:
Reply: MDTM
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SIZE
Reply: MLST type*;size*;modify*
Reply: MLSD
Reply: UTF8
Reply: CLNT
Reply: MFMT
Reply: 211 End
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/" is current directory.
Status: Current path is /
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,11,19,144) ---here the problem
Error: Server returned unroutable private IP address in PASV reply
```

You can see the ip address is still my internal web ip address, so the the outside company client can not tranfer the data since it can not find this ip address. Does haproxy supply some way to change their interal ip address to outside ip address? Does iptables can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have the FileZilla FTP server announce the correct external ip-address used by HA-proxy, which is something you can [configure](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Passive_mode_2) in Options --> Passive Mode Settings

Normally the Linux kernel uses helper modules that scan the clear text FTP command channel for the PASV response to dynamically change that to the correct NAT response and/or to dynamically open the related network port in iptables, but I don't know if HA-proxy has such a FTP protocol helper.